# Finding the position of an element in a 3-D vector given a pointer to it in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stdvector

So I have some 3-D vector like 
    `vector<vector<vector<Object>>>`.
I'm then adding pointers to certain elements of this vector to a `deque` object. When I look at the top element of the deque, however, I've lost the knowledge of where the element is with respect to other elements in the vector. I could store the coordinates of the position in each Object, but that takes a lot of time to initialize and lots of memory to store when the vector gets large.

How could I figure out the position, i.e. (x,y,z), of an element only given a pointer to it? I was thinking of changing the method of storage to an array and using arithmetic to find where it is, but I'd like to make it easier to read with a 3-D vector and also abstract the heap allocations (the size of the vector is determined at runtime).

I would like to make my code as efficient as possible. Any help would be great.

Comment: To be clear, when you put a new element into a vector, then all pointers to elements in that vector become invalid. (The vector contents could have move to a new memory location).  If you want to work with pointers to elements, you should not use `vector` as your container.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware you can't directly, if you know the vectors haven't grown, that is to say they haven't been moved to a new chunk of memory, you could take the memory address of the object you have the pointer to, minus the memory address of the first object in the array, to give you the number of the address in a single dimensional array, then you could mathematically calculate the x,y,z array accordingly. - Note this will only work if the memory is in the same chunk as it was at first, if it is not, this would also invalidate your pointer as it would no longer be pointing to a valid address

A specific problem you are trying to solve would also be helpful to know exactly what your trying to do as at the moment it is rather unclear

Edit:
The only reason this method wouldn't work is because of the pointer invalidation